When referring to a large entity (such as an organisation), do we use singular or plural?
Microsoft are forcing people to switch to Windows 11, or
Microsoft is  forcing people to switch to Windows 11?

Depends where you come from.  In British English, company and organisation names can be considered singular or plural. Both your sentences are acceptable in British English.
